# Flutter Installation with Java 9.0.4 and Studio 3.1.1 and Windows 10

Tags: android, flutter

When I run `flutter doctor -v` i get

> C:\Users\xx>flutter doctor -v 
>   [√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.2.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.371], locale en-US)
>       • Flutter version 0.2.8 at C:\Program Files\flutter
>       • Framework revision b397406561 (2 weeks ago), 2018-04-02 13:53:20 -0700
>       • Engine revision c903c217a1
>       • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.43.0.flutter-52afcba357
>
> [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
>       • Android SDK at C:\Users\aashish\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
>       • Android NDK at C:\Users\aashish\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle
>       • Platform android-P, build-tools 27.0.3
>       • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\aashish\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
>       • Java binary at: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
>       • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
>       X Android license status unknown.
>
> [X] Android Studio (not installed)
>       • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
>         (or visit https://flutter.io/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).
>
> [!] Connected devices
>       ! No devices available
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.

I tried -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions in sdkmanager (C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin) which didn't workout

Any other suggestions to get it working? or only way is to downgrade to Java 8

Comment: have you installed android studio on your system or not

Comment: if you have install android studio then in console just try to run "flutter config --android-studio-dir  you path to android studio"

Comment: @krishankTripathi No luck. I already have android studio installed with Android P, 8 SDK installed

Comment: did you do it like this  flutter config --android-studio-dir= you studio path here

Comment: if this not work let me know

Comment: I have tried flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk" as well as flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin" nothing works! Still stuck at the same point

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems is that you have JDK 9. Flutter (and possibly Android) would work with JDK  version 8. Just download the free jdk from jdk.java.net, uncompress it to a folder (or install), then set your machine's JAVA_HOME env to that folder. Restart and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Well i am still looking for a solution issues now but if you really want to start development not into you can use any other platform like Intell J idea and other as **flutter only needs an android sdk and editor** to get started for flutter the reason why **flutter have to depend in android studio is due to its gradle dependency** which you can donwload manually and start to develop using any other edtior where android development enivironment is present. You can see the following link for further reference

https://ifdevthentalk.com/2017/05/29/flutter-on-windows-without-android-studio/

Answer (score 0):

you have to install any of those to start developing flutter

> - Android Studio
> - Intelij
> - Visual Studio Code

After installing any of those locate the sdk you have and install flutter and dart plugins
Finally Run in order

```
flutter doctor
```

then

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Answer (score 0):

just > flutter doctor --android-licenses